# WhatsApp crashes on chat with business accounts

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

When I start a conversation against a business account, WhatsApp crashes.

I can briefly see the profile picture of the contact, but it crashes before I can start writing anything.

I can see the contact's information, like address and map location, but no chat.

Tried even wiping data.

Comment: Best to report it as a bug. If wiping data doesn't solve the problem (and assuming you are running the latest available version) that it is a bug and can only be resolved by developers of Whatsapp.

Comment: Yeah. And it's a long-been-there bug. Second or third time this happens to me. If I'm not mistaken, happenned even after wiping the phone. Funny nobody elese reports anything similar.

Comment: It's happening again. My brother changed his account to business. Started right away. Now it's a big problem. Must be related to this phone specifically, because no one else is reporting this problem. Uninstalling and reconfiguring it without the backups didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug caused by WA Tweaker xposed module

More specifically, when the user chooses to hide the Video or Audio call button

The bug was fixed on the latest release (V 1.6.2, 160106028armeabi-v7a)

Comment: Whether this will become obsolete or not, it's great to know about the bug though, and we don't know if anyone else outside there also has the same issue or not (and haven't updated yet). I'd suggest mentioning the specific version and/or release date that fixed this issue instead.

Comment: Changes made to the answer to include the details.  I had the idea of deleting it because, in my mind, for this app specifically, I don't think anyone will stick to the old version, as they probably seize to work when Whatsapp updates itself.